# How to access a attribute in Python dataclass?

Tags: python, class, python-dataclasses

aI'm trying to write A dataclass for my python program , My idea was to use the dataclass as a local variable holder, But I do not know how to access the variable from a dataclass.

I'd be glad if Someone would be able to point me in the right direction.

```
@dataclass
class database:
    """The whole program database that holds all the variables"""

    def birth_database():

        birthdate_add_pass : str = None
        birth_day : int = None
        birth_month : int = None
        birth_year : int = None
        full_birth_date : str = f"{birth_day}/{birth_month}/{birth_year}"

        confirm_birthday : str = None
        confirm_birthmonth : str = None
        confirm_birthyear : str = None
        confirm_full_birthdate : str = None


user_birthdate = database.birth_database.birth_day
```

Comment: Your "database" has no data. It only has empty local variables.

Comment: That’s just not how that works at all.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are confusing the concept class and method. You might want to have a look into that.

Answering your question:
You are declaring your variables inside your instance method (which won't work by the way because it's inside a class without a self) and not under the scope of the data class, this means that these variables would only exist 'inside this method'.

There are quite a lot of errors here and there, but probably what you want looks something like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class BirthDatabase:
    birthdate_add_pass: str = None
    birth_day: int = None
    birth_month: int = None
    birth_year: int = None

    confirm_birthday: str = None
    confirm_birthmonth: str = None
    confirm_birthyear: str = None
    confirm_full_birthdate: str = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.full_birth_date: str = f"{self.birth_day}/{self.birth_month}/{self.birth_year}"


user_birthdata = BirthDatabase(birth_day=10, birth_month=8, birth_year=2023)

print(user_birthdata.birth_day)  # prints: 10
print(user_birthdata.full_birth_date)
```

Anyway, this is probably not a good approach to solving your problem and other solutions might fit better your objective.

Hope this help, and if you are not using any IDE I recommend you use pycharm.
Further reading on classes:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html
https://realpython.com/python-classes/

For further info on data classes:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Answer (score -1):

```
class database:
"""The whole program database that holds all the variables"""

    class birth_database:
        def __init__(self):
            self.birthdate_add_pass : str = None
            self.birth_day : int = None
            self.birth_month : int = None
            self.birth_year : int = None
            self.full_birth_date : str = f"{self.birth_day}/{self.birth_month}/{self.birth_year}"

            self.confirm_birthday : str = None
            self.confirm_birthmonth : str = None
            self.confirm_birthyear : str = None
            self.confirm_full_birthdate : str = None


user_birthdate = database.birth_database().birth_day
```

Comment: What is the dataclass even doing here…? Nothing.

Comment: I agree. But I copied it over from his code.
Edit: I removed it

Comment: Now what does `class database` do here? Still nothing.

Comment: Maybe it does. I don't know what his full codebase looks like. Maybe he has other classes in `database`

Comment: Even if they did, that would still be fairly pointless. Nested classes simply aren't a thing in Python and serve little purpose. OP is just thoroughly confused about what they want to do, no need to copy any of their existing structure.